# Is it possible to search by posts that contain an image?

Tags: discussion, support, search

Sometimes when going back through e.g. my previous answers to find some information, I know the question I am looking for contains an image, and I know the language tag, but I'm a little hazy on the other parameters.

Is there a search option to restrict results to only those posts that contain an image? Akin to filtering email to show only those with attachments I guess.

I see that with [advanced-search](/questions/tagged/advanced-search) you can filter by user, votes, answer count or whether a question has an accepted answer, or has been closed or migrated. But not images?

Comment: No such option right now, feature request already exists. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the link. I swear I did search for this! :-)

Comment: No worry, [happens to me all the time](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a152859%20closed%3ayes)! :)

Comment: Not ideal, but `url:"*.jpg*"` and related isn't an *completely* insane way to work-around this with the current operators.  [Try it here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.jpg*%22)