# How can I sort answers that comprise at least 1 picture by votes?

Tags: support, answers, search, images

I've always loved  Math SE's [[visualization]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization) tag, and posts like [Visually stunning math concepts which are easy to explain](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/733754/). Some people learn best visually. Other SE's like Math Educators and Chemistry don't have this tag, but doubtless they both use images.

1. So how can I see a list of answers, ordered by votes, that comprise at least one picture?
2. Is it possible to sort by a second criterion : the number of text in that answer? Then I can see which posts with at least one picture has the least and most accompanying text.

Comment: Right now you can't search directly for pictures in posts, there's a feature request requesting it though: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156639/369802. I don't know if you can use SEDE for this, that's probably the best next option. Another possible workaround could be the comment here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212379/is-it-possible-to-search-by-posts-that-contain-an-image#comment683410_212379

Comment: SEDE was my thought as well, but it's offline right now :(

Comment: It is not exactly what you want, but you could search for answers with urls containing [imgur](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*imgur*%22+is:a),
[png](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*png*%22+is:a),
[jpg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*jpg*%22+is:a),
[gif](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*gif*%22+is:a), ... (And sort the search results by votes.)

Comment: There is also a related question on [math.meta.se]: [What is the efficient way to search post with pictures/images?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9402)

Comment: Some of the [good answers don't have an image](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3672591/510296) but are strictly MathJax; yet the arrangement of the numbers is clear, that an *image* is conveyed. --- Just saying that you'll miss a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1281338).

I take a slightly different approach. Instead of searching in the html (that is found in the Posts.body field) I use the actual markdown as source. This is more complicated (and performs worse) because the PostHistory table contains all revisions of a post, not only the latest one. So I do some juggling to find the last revision. In that text I use the same technique Glorfindel used: a Like statement but I look for the `![ ][ ]` markdown. Instead of length of the text I added a rough estimate of the word count.

To keep SEDE happy I do a TOP 1000.

```sql
select top 1000
       a.id as [Post Link]
     , a.creationdate
     , a.score
     , len(text)-len(replace(text,' ','')) [~ word count]
from posts a
inner join posts q on q.id = a.parentid
inner join (
select postid, 
       text
from posthistory phi
where id = (select max(id) 
            from posthistory ph
            where ph.postid = phi.postid
            and ph.posthistorytypeid in (2,5,8))
) md on md.postid = a.id
where a.posttypeid = 2 -- answers
and (
  md.text like '%![[]%][[]%]%' 
  --or 
  --md.text like '%![%](%)%' or 
  --md.text like '%<img src="%"%'
  )
order by 4 desc
```

This is what the result looks like:

[image: result with answers and word count]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the fine [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the admirable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Answer (score 4):

The best results you'll probably get with SEDE, since it should allow for your second criterion (sorting by length of the post).

But for the first part, you can use a search: `[visualization] url:"*.jpg*" is:a` to find answers within the visualization tag that have an image, then sort the results by votes.

Like Martin said in the comments under your question, to find as many answers as possible you might want to search for multiple urls, containing imgur, png, jpg and gif.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/matheducators/query/1281137/highest-scoring-answers-with-at-least-one-image) is a SEDE query listing all answers with at least one image. Figuring out how much text an answer has is too hard (at least for me) so I settled for the total length of the answer which should give a good indication.

Note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning, and [currently it has some availability problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353140/295232). Also, searching the full Posts table like this probably doesn't work on larger sites like Mathematics; it does work for Chemistry and Mathematics Educators. You might need to fork the query e.g. to limit your search to certain tags, minimum score or posting date. Check out the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) if you're new to SEDE or SQL in general.